# Magento 2 - How to override Method getShippingMethodTitle in Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, requirejs-config.js, mixins

I need to override the method `getShippingMethodTitle` which is defined in **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js**.

The Method gets the shipping method title in the checkout in the summary:

[image]

I tried to override it by using a mixing like this:

**Company/Shipping/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping': {
                'Company_Shipping/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

I also tried this:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping': {
                'Company_Shipping/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

**Company/Shipping/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin.js**:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
], function (wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        getShippingMethodTitle: function () {
            var shippingMethod = '',
                shippingMethodTitle = '';

            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return '';
            }
            shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();

            if (typeof shippingMethod['method_title'] !== 'undefined') {
                shippingMethodTitle = ' - ' + shippingMethod['method_title'];
            }

            return shippingMethod ?
                shippingMethod['carrier_title'] + shippingMethodTitle + " foo" :
                shippingMethod['carrier_title'];
        },
    };

    /**
     * Override default getShippingMethodTitle
     */
    return function (target) {
        return wrapper.extend(target, mixin);
    };
});
```

**Attempt 2 - [Extend JS Function](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html#extend-js-function):**

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping': {
                'Company_Shipping/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

**shipping-mixin.js:**

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
], function (wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (getShippingMethodTitle) {
        return wrapper.wrap(getShippingMethodTitle, function (originalGetShippingMethodTitle, config, element) {

            var shippingMethod = '',
                shippingMethodTitle = '';

            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return '';
            }
            shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();

            if (typeof shippingMethod['method_title'] !== 'undefined') {
                shippingMethodTitle = ' - ' + shippingMethod['method_title'];
            }

            return shippingMethod ?
                shippingMethod['carrier_title'] + shippingMethodTitle + " foo" :
                shippingMethod['carrier_title'];
        });
    };
});
```

**Attempt 3 - [Extend JS Object:](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html#extend-js-object)**

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping': {
                'Company_Shipping/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

**shipping-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
], function (wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (shipping) {
        shipping.getShippingMethodTitle = wrapper.wrapSuper(shipping.getShippingMethodTitle, function () {
            this._super();
            // add extended functionality here or modify method logic altogether
            var shippingMethod = '',
                shippingMethodTitle = '';

            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return '';
            }
            shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();

            if (typeof shippingMethod['method_title'] !== 'undefined') {
                shippingMethodTitle = ' - ' + shippingMethod['method_title'];
            }

            return shippingMethod ?
                shippingMethod['carrier_title'] + shippingMethodTitle + " foo" :
                shippingMethod['carrier_title'];
        });

        return shipping;
    };
});
```

But it does not work and still loads the old method. I added `foo` to the title but it is not showing. Of course I flushed the cache with `bin/magento c:f`.
What is wrong with my mixin?

Please only show solutions which show how to override that method, I don't want to override the whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the code from the documentation wrong. To make it work I have to use the code showed in the chapter **Extend UI Component**. I think I copied the code from somewhere from the internet and thought it is from the documentation. So it was my fault.

I was using the wrong return statement as pointed out by @mrtuvn [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30569)

I used this (wrong):

```
return function (target) {
    return wrapper.extend(target, mixin);
};
```

instead of this (correct):

```
return function (target) { // target == Result that Magento_Ui/.../columns returns.
    return target.extend(mixin); // new result that all other modules receive
};
```

Working Code:

**Company/Shipping/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping': {
                'Company_Shipping/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

**Company/Shipping/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin.js**:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
], function (wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        getShippingMethodTitle: function () {
            var shippingMethod = '',
                shippingMethodTitle = '';

            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return '';
            }
            shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();

            if (typeof shippingMethod['method_title'] !== 'undefined') {
                shippingMethodTitle = ' - ' + shippingMethod['method_title'];
            }

            return shippingMethod ?
                shippingMethod['carrier_title'] + shippingMethodTitle + " foo" :
                shippingMethod['carrier_title'];
        },
    };

    /**
     * Override default getShippingMethodTitle
     */
    return function (OriginShipping) {
        return OriginShipping.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are on the right path. Perhaps you need to manually find and delete Magento's requirejs-config.js from your Magento static assets directory, so that it is regenerated to include the new mixin. You can do this using the following command:

```
find pub | grep requirejs-config.js
rm path/to/requirejs-config.js
```

Once deleted, if you are running in production mode, redeploy static assets and clear your browser cache before testing again.

Comment: Nah thats not the problem either, I executed `grunt clean`. And one should never ever develop in production mode btw

Comment: If you manually inspect Magento's requirejs-config.js from the browser's Network tab, does it include the Company_Shipping mixin anywhere?

Comment: Yes It does, just checked it. I solved the problem an hour ago and posted the answer.